# F# Find all files in subdirectories modified within the last 5 days

Tags: f#

I am fairly new to F# so please be gentle.  I am trying to write code in a functional style to look through a directory (and subdirectories) for all files modified within the last 5 days and then do something with those files (at the moment that is just to write the name to the console).

The code I have is:

```
open System.IO

let rec getAllFiles dir pattern =
    seq { yield! Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, pattern)
          for d in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir) do
              yield! getAllFiles d pattern }

let printMe x = printfn "%A" x

let hasChangedRecently fileName =
    let myFile = System.IO.FileInfo(fileName)
    let f myFile = function
    | myFile when myFile.LastWriteTime >= System.DateTime.Parse "10-04-2015" -> printMe MyFile.Name
    | _ -> ()

    f fileName

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    getAllFiles @"c:\temp" "*.xml"
    |> Seq.iter hasChangedRecently

    System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

It is all going wrong in the hasChangedRecently block.

The errors are:

```
myFile.LastWriteTime
Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.

MyFile.Name
The namespace or module 'MyFile' is not defined

|> Seq.iter hasChangedRecently
Type mismatch. Expecting a
string -> unit    
but given a
string -> 'a -> unit    
The type 'unit' does not match the type ''a -> unit'
```

I am quite sure these are basic errors but would sincerely appreciate some guidance.

Comment: For what it's worth, `EnumerateFiles` [has an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx) that does the recursion for you by searching all subdirectories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would change the `hasRecentlyChanged` to be `string -> bool` function and filter the files with it, then have a separate function to print the files.

```
let hasChangedRecently fileName =
    let myFile = System.IO.FileInfo(fileName)
    myFile.LastWriteTime >= System.DateTime.Parse "10-04-2015"

let printFile file =
    printfn "%s" file
```

and in `main`:

```
getAllFiles @"c:\temp" "*.xml"
|> Seq.filter hasChangedRecently
|> Seq.iter printFile
```

Also, if you want, you can avoid `getAllFiles` been recursive by using `SearchOption.AllDirectories` built into .NET:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Comment: You could define the `printFile` function like this if you wanted, and get the same result: `let printFile = printfn "%s"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also rewrite `hasChangedRecently` like that (and let it print the result)

```
let hasChangedRecently fileName =
    match  System.IO.FileInfo(fileName) with
    | myFile when myFile.LastWriteTime >= System.DateTime.Parse "10-04-2015" -> printfn "%s" myFile.Name
    | _ -> ()
```

if you want to use function you'll have somehow to help the compiler in infering the type. In this case you can write:

```
let hasChangedRecently fileName =
    let analyze: (System.IO.FileInfo -> _) = 
        function 
        | x when x.LastAccessTime > System.DateTime.Parse "10-04-2015" -> printfn "%s" x.Name 
        | _ -> ()
    analyze System.IO.FileInfo(fileName)
```

As Vandroiy explained very well in his comment, `function` does pattern matching on the unnamed argument. Here we just defined the type of `analyze` as a function taking a FileInfo in argument and returning whatever.

Comment: Yes, that works as well, thank you.  Please can you explain what I was doing wrong.  When should I use the function keyword and when should I use a straight 'match'?

Comment: well, I think there were several problems in your code since you reused myFile as the argument of your "f" function. In the definition of your f function, the compiler was unable to infer the type of this myFile argument. But even if you replace myFile with x, let's say, and give type annotation, it still doesn't work with 'function'. I've got to investigate why... Meanwhile, I must confess that in that kind of  cases I often let me driven by the compiler and change my code until he no longer shouts.

Comment: @PeterB `function` declares a function that takes one unnamed argument and does pattern matching on it. In other words, it means something like `fun arg0 -> match arg0 with`. In the question, the code `let f myFile = function` creates a function with *two* arguments, where the first gets bound to the name `myFile` and the second goes into the pattern match. Then, in the pattern matcher, `myFile` gets bound again, shadowing the function argument, which is never used.

Comment: @Vandroiy exactly! after a good night, I came with fresher ideas and wanted to give the same explanation. I'll edit my answer to illustrate it